# Is different font sizes possible in a button in javafx

Tags: css, button, javafx, javafx-2

```
    final Button btnl2 = new Button("SIGN IN");
    btnl2.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 16));
    btnl2.setPrefSize(150, 60);
    btnl2.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");
    Image imageOk1 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("signin.png"));
    btnl2.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageOk1));
```

This is the code of one of the buttons in my project. The .png image is displayed in middle of the button. I want to know 2 things :

1) Is it possible to display it to the left side of the button ?

2) Is it possible to have different font sizes in the button ? Now my button has "SIGN IN" label on it. I want to add a new label to the same button with a different font size below the "SIGN IN" label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) yes IIRC it is named ContentDisplay but i could be wrong and it's named differently
2) yes but you don't use the text attribute any more but eg but a mixtutre of hbox/vbox/label/imageview on the graphic attribute who accepts a Node

```
Button b = new Button();
VBox box = new VBox();
box.getChildren().addAll(new Label("line1"), new Label("line2"));
b.setGraphic(box);
```

Comment: Can you provide me an example ?